# Build nested Object/Array with jquery

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a javascript object from the inputs of a dynamic form. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
fieldTickets = [];
thisWeek = randomDateOnSunday;
weekDay = randomWeekDayWithinTheWeek;
fieldTickets[thisWeek]['days'][weekDay]['fieldTechs'].push({name: fieldTechName});
```

As you can see, I have some keys that are dynamic variables and some that are defined ('days' and 'fieldTechs' are always the same, but the week and weekday will change). Unfortunately every time I try to run this, even on fiddles, it gives me `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'days')` as an error. I've been dealing with this for hours and can't figure it out.

How does one build a nested array/object with dynamic keys?

Comment: You check if they exist, and create them if they don't, before assigning. Not sure what this has to do with jQuery though, this is just plain JS behaviour.

Comment: i thought that it would create it automatically if it didn't exist by using that syntax...obviously I'm wrong but is there another shorter way than a ton of `if exists` statements?

Comment: Please provide an [mre] showing the behavior you are discussing. Also, this has nothing to do with jQuery; there is no DOM or ajax interaction here.

Comment: There is no way the interpreter would be able to guess at what those intermediate values would even be. Plain objects? Why? Why not Date objects in this case? Or a class you declared earlier? And that's why it doesn't: it can't guess for you, you're responsible for making sure the data structures are set up before you access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i thought that it would create it automatically if it didn't exist by
> using that syntax...obviously I'm wrong but is there another shorter
> way than a ton of if exists statements?

JavaScript will not create it automatically, but can do it without `if`, try something like below

```js
const thisWeek = '12'; //randomDateOnSunday;
const weekDay = 'Sunday'; // randomWeekDayWithinTheWeek;

fieldTickets = {
  [thisWeek]: {
    days: {
      [weekDay]: {
        fieldTechs: []
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log('fieldTickets:', fieldTickets);

// pushing 
fieldTickets[thisWeek]['days'][weekDay]['fieldTechs'].push({
  name: "Hello"
});

// pushing again
fieldTickets[thisWeek]['days'][weekDay]['fieldTechs'].push({
  name: "World"
});
console.log('fieldTickets 2:', fieldTickets);
```